# How to call a Image from assets to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

i am trying to make a user Post a Image, with an UIImage Picker but i also want to make a simulate user which post a Picture by calling a function where the parameters are a UIImage and a the User who called the function the function creats a Object from the struct Post which store the data which are needed for the Post this Object get than stoared in an Array called feed. and than on the watchFeedview i go over it with an forEach and give the Postview the post object so he knows the data to put in.

```
    mutating func makePost(image: UIImage,appUser: User) {
    
    //guard let image = image else { return }

    let post: Post = Post(ersteller: appUser, image: image, datum: "2022")
    
    feed.append(post)
    
    for i in 0..<friends.count {
        friends[i].feed.append(post)
    }

struct Post: Identifiable {

var id = UUID()
@State var ersteller: User = User()
@State var image: UIImage?
var datum: String = ""
@State var likes: Int = 0

init(ersteller: User, image: UIImage, datum: String) {
    self.ersteller = ersteller
    self.image = image
    self.datum = datum
}
```

}

i Think he doesnt can give the UIImage to the parameter or dosent find it in the assets

user.makePost(image: UIImage(systemName: "person")!, appUser: user)

Comment: You mean that you have image named "person" is inside your xcassets?  Then use `UIImage(named: "person")`, which is ~ linked to "SF Symbols". See the doc of each methods.

Comment: sry i forgot to change the name i tried to user al system Image so i can test if the hole thing doesnt work or just with the image

Comment: Using State property wrapper on a type that's not a SwiftUI View seems like a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Make something like this:

`UIImage(named: "imageFromAsset")`